# Microsoft Excel 2010...nesting in IF function

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have been trying to nest multiple statements in the if function...
I want to put in two commands in the "value if true" part of the If function....for example, if a particular condition holds true, I want excel to write "old employ" in Cell "B 2" and "Left service" in cell "C 2"....is it possible??
I tried this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,"the range of payroll IDs",1,FALSE))=TRUE,B2="old Employ"C2="Left Service","still in service")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,"the range of payroll IDs",1,FALSE)=TRUE,"Old employee","still in service")
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,"the range of payroll IDs",1,FALSE)=TRUE,"Left Service","still in service")
```

It is possible to nest if statement but it is not possible to write info in other cell using formula. You will need some VBA to do the job for you. Otherwise put the relevant formula into column B and C.

Answer (score 0):

Use following link for if function in excel

http://www.gleegrid.com/t/v/12/Excel-if-function-Gleegrid.com

Comment: please put some more information .. dont just put link in answer